# Failure of "directedness" for second-order logic?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, higher-order-logics

Say that a logic $\mathcal{L}$ is **directed** iff whenever $\mathfrak{A}\equiv_\mathcal{L}\mathfrak{B}$ there is some $\mathfrak{C}$ with $\mathcal{L}$-elementary substructures $\mathfrak{A}'\preccurlyeq_\mathcal{L}\mathfrak{C}$, $\mathfrak{B}'\preccurlyeq_\mathcal{L}\mathfrak{C}$ with $\mathfrak{A}\cong\mathfrak{A}',\mathfrak{B}\cong\mathfrak{B}'$. It's a standard exercise to show that $\mathsf{FOL}$ is directed - or more generally, that every *compact* logic is directed. On the other hand, it's easy to whip up artificial logics demonstrating that this joint embeddability isn't *equivalent* to compactness.

I'm curious about the situation with second-order logic $\mathsf{SOL}$. It's consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that there are $\mathsf{SOL}$-equivalent structures which do not $\mathsf{SOL}$-elementarily embed into the same structure (see below), but I don't see how to get this result outright in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (much less $\mathsf{ZF}$). However, I recall seeing an easy argument (due to Mostowski?) that in fact this is a $\mathsf{ZF}$-theorem.

> **Question**: Does $\mathsf{ZF}$ prove that $\mathsf{SOL}$ is not directed?

Here's a proof that the non-directedness of $\mathsf{SOL}$ is *consistent* with $\mathsf{ZF}$. Suppose there is a family $\mathbb{A}$ of amorphous sets of pairwise incomparable cardinality such that there is no injection from $\mathbb{A}$ into $2^{\aleph_0}$. Thinking of each element of $\mathbb{A}$ as a structure in the empty language, we must have $X,Y\in\mathbb{A}$ with $X\equiv_\mathsf{SOL}Y$ but $X\not\cong Y$. But any set into which both $X$ and $Y$ inject must be non-amorphous, hence cannot satisfy $Th_\mathsf{SOL}(X)=Th_\mathsf{SOL}(Y)$ since amorphousness is second-order-expressible.

Of course this doesn't help at all without a background assumption of lots of amorphous sets, so it's not really relevant to the question I'm asking here, but it's still neat. Note that a positive answer will have to crucially involve uncountable structures, since [it's consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that $\equiv_{\mathsf{SOL}}$ implies $\cong$ for countable structures](https://mathoverflow.net/a/161694/8133).

Comment: Non-directedness of SOL is also consistent with ZFC.  Assume ZFC + "there is no strong cardinal".  Then a pressing-down argument gives $\lambda$ such that no $\alpha < \lambda$ is $\lambda$-strong.  By pigeonhole, there are two structures $A = (V_\lambda; \in, \alpha)$ and $B = (V_\lambda; \in, \beta)$ with the same second-order theory (vocabulary contains $\in$ and a constant symbol.)  Given C with the same second-order theory, we may assume wlog $C = (V_\mu; \in, \gamma)$.  But A and B can't both elementarily embed into C; one embedding would be non-identity, witnessing $\lambda$-strongness.

Comment: @TrevorWilson Ah, nice, I didn't see that. Surely this is an outright $\mathsf{ZF}$-theorem, though, or at least a $\mathsf{ZFC}$-theorem ... right?

Comment: Maybe; I haven't thought about it enough to say.  I don't have any good reason to think strong cardinals are actually relevant; that was just the first thing that occurred to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to the question is yes.

Let $\alpha_0<\alpha_1$ be the least ordinals (in the reverse lex order, say) such that $V_{\alpha_0}$ and $V_{\alpha_1}$ have the same second order theory $T$. Assume towards a contradiction that $V_{\alpha_0}$ and $V_{\alpha_1}$ are elementarily embeddable into a common structure $M$, which we may assume is transitive. Note that the embeddings fix $T$. Since $V_{\alpha_1}$ satisfies that there is an ordinal $\beta$ such that $V_\beta$ satisfies $T$, so does $M$, and hence so does $V_{\alpha_0}$. But this means that some $\beta < \alpha_0$ has the same theory as $V_{\alpha_0}$, contrary to the minimality of the pair $\alpha_0 < \alpha_1$.
(Edit: I now see this is very close to what Trevor was doing.)

Comment: Ah, yes, I missed that - thanks!